# How do I specify HTML5 attributes with Struts 2.x?

Tags: html, struts

I make extensive use of Struts2 in my application. Now I want to add HTML5 attributes like `autocorrect` and `type="email"`. I don't see any HTML5 plugin. Is there a standard way to the `<s:textfield..>` tag for example?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can add `HTML5` attributes directly into the `textfield` tag. I've done it successfully with `pattern`, `min` and `max`, they are correctly rendered in the HTML.

```
<s:textfield type="number" name="..." value="%{...}" pattern="[0-9]+" min="40" max="700" />
```

Comment: Thanks - now I see the `<dynamic-attributes>true</dynamic-attributes>` in the .tld file :)