# How to introduce HTML5 tag attributes and HTML5+CSS form validation for Struts2 tag elements

Tags: css, html, validation, struts2

We are with extensive struts2 in our application. Now challenging task is to remove all struts2 default validation and introduce HTML5 with Css validation.

Example for struts2 form

```
<s:form id="userForm" action="userAction" method="post" validate="true">
   <s:password key="Pwd" required="true" maxlength="128" />
 </s:form>
```

in this i want to use HTML5 attribute "type=password" and "required" and pattern="(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-zA-Z])\w{7,}" and want to make CSS validation for all these. How can i do this. Explanation with example or any related tutorial more appreciated.

I want this to explain the problem I am facing with css validation

Bellow is my struts form

```
      <s:form id="userForm" action="userAction" method="post" validate="true">
       <s:password key="Pwd" type="email" required="true" maxlength="128" id="password"             pattern="(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-zA-Z])\w{7,}"/>
       <span class="form_hint">Password should contain,</br> 
                1.minimum of 7 characters. </br> 
                2. Must consist of only letters and digits.</br> 
                3.At least one letter and at least one digit</span>
       </s:submit type="button"> 
     </s:form>
```

I want to validate this password field for 
1.required means user entered or not before submit,
2.password meets the given pattern criteria if yes i want to turn  text to green color.

and my css is as bellow,

```
 .form_hint {
        background: #d45252;
        border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
        color: white;
        margin-left:8px;
        padding: 1px 6px;
        z-index: 999; 
        position: absolute;
        display: none;
    }

    .form_hint::before {
        content: "\25C0"; 
        color:#d45252;
        position: absolute;
        top:1px;
        left:-6px;
    }
    #emailId input:focus + .form_hint {
        display: inline;
    }

    #emailId input:required:valid + .form_hint { 
        background: #28921f;
    }

    #emailId input:required:valid + .form_hint::before {
        color:#28921f;
    }
```

But on screen when i click submit button with invalid password, just HTML5 pattern tag attribute is working with a message like "Please enter required format". how to make my css effective. what syntax I have to use in my CSS file. I mean "#emailId input:focus + .form_hint", "#emailId input:required:valid + .form_hint", "#emailId input:required:valid + .form_hint::before" are not taking effect in my form.

Comment: It should work, S2 supports dynamic attributes.

Comment: @LukaszLenart: on certain UI Tags only, though

Comment: So what stops you? Just do it.

Comment: Your `form_hint` span isn't adjacent sibling of textfield.

Comment: @Aleksandr M -I think my css syntax is not correct...can you please check it once

Comment: please create a [Fiddle](http://jsFiddle.net)

Comment: sorry but how can i do with struts2 tags?

Comment: No, your span is not a next element after textfield, at least not in this form that you have shown. Check rendered HTML.

Comment: create a fiddle by posting the generated HTML (click View Source, then copy and paste :)

Comment: Ya input is inside <fieldset> and <div> this is how struts renders the page. but still   "#emailId input:required:valid + .form_hint"(i,e span changing to gree color) if pw is correct is not working. I checked the inspect element.

Answer (score 2):

I have used jquery validation-engine with struts tag to apply css validations and have successfully implemented it.

This is the link of the tutorial I followed for jquery-validation engine:

http://www.skill-guru.com/blog/2010/04/18/jquery-validation-tutorial/

and this is how my struts tags look like :)

```
  <s:textfield name="tenant.shortName" label="Short Name" labelSeparator=" " id="shortName" maxlength="3"
                    cssClass="validate[required,custom[noSpecialCaracters]] text-input"></s:textfield>
```

**EDIT**
OK so if you insist on using html5 this is your solution :

[How do I specify HTML5 attributes with Struts 2.x?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11074087/how-do-i-specify-html5-attributes-with-struts-2-x) ...

and for using css you can use cssClass="" in struts tags for your css classes.

Note the span won't work inside `<s:form>` as `<s:form>` will flourish as tables when it is expanded by taglib. It is never adjacent to password in expanded html code..

**One suggestion**: You can use the title attribute to show things you want to on mouse hover.. or tooltip attribute in `<s>` tags

Comment: ya but I don't want to use jquery. I want to use only HTML5 and CSS with struts2 similar to (http://www.developerdrive.com/2013/08/html5-and-css3-form-validation/)

Answer (score 0):

You are probably using the [default XHTML Theme](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/xhtml-theme.html), that will generate additional HTML for you (the `<fieldset>` for example).

Then

1. switch to the [Simple Theme](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/simple-theme.html), to gain full control over the generated HTML,
2. or, since your two fields are no more adjacent, use the `~` ([General Sibling Combinator](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#general-sibling-combinators)) instead of the `+` ([Adjacent Sibling Combinator](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#adjacent-sibling-combinators)).